# Object doesn't add with children - EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

It's been quite a while since I last used EF. I've never had any problems using it before. Now I'm attempting to insert an object that has a one-many relationship with another object. But in the API call, the collection array of the child object is shown to be empty however the parent object can be seen in the api call of the child object.

I have my models as below:

**Conversation Table**

```
 public class Conversation
{
    public Conversation()
    {
        this.ChatMessages = new List<ChatMessage>();
        this.DeletedConversations = new List<ConversationDeleted>();
    }
    public int ConversationID { get; set; }
    public string toUser { get; set; }
    public string FromUser { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Conversation")]
    public ICollection<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConversationDeleted> DeletedConversations { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

**ChatMessage Table**

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    public int ChatMessageID { get; set; }
    public string fromUser { get; set; }
    public string toUser { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool DeliveryStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueID { get; set; }
    public int ConversationID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ConversationID")]
    public virtual Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MessageDeleted> MessagesDeleted { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

}
```

My Fluent API looks like this:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChatMessage>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Conversation)
                .WithMany(x => x.ChatMessages)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ConversationID);
```

I'm trying to create a conversation entity and add a chat object to it's collection. I do it like so:

```
   public IHttpActionResult CreateConversation()
    {
        ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage { CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow, DeliveryStatus = true, fromUser = "annettehiggs", toUser = "terrydriscoll", Message = "Hum tum", UniqueID = Guid.NewGuid(), UserId = 43 };
        Conversation conv = new Conversation();
        conv.ChatMessages.Add(msg);
        conv.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        conv.FromUser = "annettehiggs";
        conv.toUser = "terrydriscoll";

        DataModel db = new DataModel();
        db.Conversations.Add(conv);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(conv);
    }
```

and this is how I retrieve the conversation object:

```
   public IQueryable<Conversation> GetConversations()
    {
        return db.Conversations;
    }
```

As a result, ChatMessage API call shows the conversation it's associated to but the Conversation object doesn't show the chat in it's collection. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the problem with saving data or with retrieval? The code you shared is for saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The add code is working properly (otherwice you'll not be able to see the new chat message). The problem is with your data retrieval code.

Since your `ChatMessage.Conversation` property is marked as `virtual`, most probably it gets [lazy loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy), that's why you see it populated.

At the same time, your `Conversation.ChatMessages` is not `virtual`, hence you need to explicitly [eager load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager) it using the `Inlclude` method, or depending on your requirements, mark it `virtual` to get the lazy load behavior like the inverse navigation property.

Comment: Yep I figured that before I read this. Thanks for providing your insight :)